# perl foreach array result from a database

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash, dbi

I have some `select` result from database(like on image).

[image: db select]

I need do `foreach` cycle for `id`

It's must looks like this

```
foreach () {
   if ($status==1) {
      if ($process_id ~~ @some_array) {
    #do something
   }
}
```

How do for each cycle? As I understand I need to get a result from a base in hash form `$ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref`, but I never worked with him, and my attempts were unsuccessful. Help me please.

Comment: What code do you have so far? `$sth->fetchrow` type methods can be called in a `while` loop to fetch and process one at a time

Comment: I can to get the arrays of the form
`943 1 0 0`
But it's not true for me. Code like 

`while($ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
        @keys = keys %$ref;
        @values = values %$ref;
}` does not fit too

Comment: A hash lookup would be better than using (experimental) `~~ @array` because it's faster and because it won't change on you. `my %some_array = map { $_ => 1 } @some_array;`, then `if ($some_array{$process_id}) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `fetchrow_array` what you need?

```
while (my ($id, $status, $process_id, $error_count) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    if (1 == $status and grep $_ == $process_id, @some_array) {
        # do something
    }
}
```